# Why is the last word not showing in this string?

Tags: arrays, c, string

Why is the last word not showing?? When I run the code and input words then one output is missing.

If I input : `It is a cat`

Output should be  :

```
It
is
A
Cat
```

All words will be printed on separate lines.

But `Cat` is not showing.

Here is the code :

```c
#incnlude <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
   char s[1002],word[100];
   int i,j,length, is_word_started;

   gets(s);
   length = strlen(s);
   is_word_started = 0;

   for(i = 0,j = 0;i < length;i++) {
      if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')  {
         if(is_word_started == 0) {
            is_word_started = 1;
            word[j] = 'A' + s[i] - 'a';
            j++;
         }
         else {
            word[j] = s[i];
            j++;
         }
      }


      else if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
         if(is_word_started == 0) {
            is_word_started = 1;
         }
         word[j] = s[i];
         j++;
      }


      else if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
         if(is_word_started == 0) {
            is_word_started = 1;
         }
         word[j] = s[i];
      }


      else {
         if(is_word_started == 1) {
            is_word_started = 0;
            word[j] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n",word);
            j = 0;
         }
      }

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code, for example print each character as you process it. And then read the documentation of `gets()`, if you find one of this ancient and since long deprecated function. Better use `fgets()`.

Comment: Try input `"it is a cat."` with a period ... or `"it is a cat!"`. Reason from the results. You only print the word when you do not match against `'a'` to `'z'` or `'0'` to `'9'`

Comment: You only print the word when you read a separator character. There's no separator after the last word. You need to print the last word after the loop ends.

Comment: @pmg But I don't want to use (. , ! etc.) punctuation. Have any solution without use punctuation ?

Comment: They're explaining how to go about testing your code to demonstrate exactly when it fails. Understanding what you code does now is the first step to fixing it - this is all part of debugging.

Comment: The quick and easy fix is to look at j after the for loop, just above the return statement. If j != 0 then you are at the end of a word you have not yet printed. Add the null terminator and run your print one more time.

Comment: Your code has lots of nested if statements.  This makes it hard to understand and debug.  It is doing exactly what you tell it to do -- which is only print a word when you start the next word.  The last word never has something starting after it so it never gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the last word not showing??

- Q: When does your code print a word?
- A: When it finds a non-alphanumeric character
- Q: Does it currently find a non-alphanumeric character after the last word?
- A: No

So, you *either* need:

1. a non-alphanumeric character after the last word (you can trivially see this by adding a `.` or something to your input string, so why not just do that first to confirm your understanding?)
2. *or* to also print output on some other condition, such as when `is_word_started` is true after the loop finishes

Option 2 looks like duplication, and there's an easy way to make option 1 always work, since [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) produces a null-terminated string: simply change the loop condition to

```
for(i = 0,j = 0; i <= length; i++) {
```

This will make the last iteration look at `s[length]`, which is guaranteed to be the terminal `\0` character.

---

NB. You should also look at the character classification functions provided in `<ctype.h>`, like [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper), [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower), [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit), and should use [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) instead of doing ASCII arithmetic.